# how to build an version API for an existing rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

how to build a version API for an existing rails app?
i have built a simple app with relation ship of User and company

```
Company has_many users

User belongs_to company
```

how can i build a *versioned* *api* for this app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directory structure for APIs

Here, ApiController is a subclass of ApplicationController, and acts as a parent class for all of the other API controllers.

```
app/controllers/
    .
    |-- api
    |   `-- v1
    |       |-- api_controller.rb
    |       |-- users_controller.rb
            |-- companies_controller.rb
    |-- application_controller.rb
```

Here's what the controllers look like:

## app/controllers/api/v1/api_controller.rb

```
module Api::V1
  class ApiController < ApplicationController
    #API stuff here
  end
end
```

## app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb

```
module Api::V1
  class UsersController < ApiController

    # POST /v1/users
    def create
      your code goes here
    end

  end
end
```

API routes

```
routes.rb

    namespace :api, defaults: {format: :json} do
      namespace :v1 do
        resources :users
      end
    end
```

API URL for user's index action, just example

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users.json
```

Comment: thnks LHH,may i know what will be the url for getting json data?